# How to add different Quality in a Single video in my website?

Tags: javascript, css, html

How can I add different Quality in videos. Do I have to embed it in  or  or any other tag . I mean I want to open a video website. Now I have to post 720p and 1080p. I have to post them separately. But I want them to be posted at once in same video . The people could change the Quality just by choosing like YouTube. Or Is there anyway I can post 2 separate button. 1. 720p 2. 1080p . By Clicking no. 1 a video will be open in the same page. Then clicking no.2 the other Quality video will open in same place as 720p video and forcing the 720p to be hidden

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages, take the SO tour, read about how to ask good questions, as well as this question checklist.@Doctor Delta

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to downscale video on YouTube manually. YouTube does this automatically, just upload the highest quality you can, and the appropriate lower qualities will be "created" in the quality settings.

Comment: The question isn't about YouTube. The OP simply references YouTube as an example of what they're referring to. The question itself is unfortunately off-topic (very broad, no specific programming question).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't asking for that. I have described it more in my question. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry the original question referenced YouTube. my bad.